# Unable to load Eclipse runtime jar using Maven in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am experiencing following exception while downloading Eclipse run time jar from Maven.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.core/runtime/3.10.0-v20140318-2214

My Maven entry is:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0-v20140318-2214</version>
            </dependency>
```

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.10.0-v20140318-2214 less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems.

How do I resolve this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

posting answer to those if anyone face the same problem and tried to resolve it. All I have to do is build ($mvn clean install) the project and re-import it again in intellij.